# How to get balance from alphanet via tzscan api?

Tags: node, transactions, tezos-client, alphanet, tzscan

hello i trying to get balance form alphanet via tzscan api. my request url were "https://api.alphanet.tzscan.io/v3/balance/tz1XgTzqC9JJNds5isd95VPaRHpVHpFX8zs2". here i only get 0 as balance which not right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This request is using the balance updates that we have disabled on alphanet.
I would recommend to use the node rpc:
https://alphanet-node.tzscan.io/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/tz1XgTzqC9JJNds5isd95VPaRHpVHpFX8zs2/balance 
But this also gives 0 so your balance is actually of 0.

Comment: thanks for response. it works